# Why is the InverseMelScale torchaudio function so slow?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, spectrogram

I am currently exploring and learning machine learning for music/audio generation and I am already failing in the first steps.
My idea is to use image-based learning algorithms on audio.
To do so, I want to convert the audio into a MEL spectrogram and then apply the machine learning  stuff.
Then, when the model is trained, it obviously should generate music again, which will be MEL spectrogram.
So I have to convert the MEL spectrogram back to audio.

Generating the MEL spectrogram is straight forward using `pytorch`'s `torchaudio` framwork:

```
waveform, _ = torchaudio.load(os.path.join(folder, "drums.mp3"), normalize=True, format="mp3")
waveform = waveform.to(device)
mel_spectrogram_transform = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate=44100, hop_length=512, n_fft=2048, n_mels=512, f_max=16384).to(device)
mel_spectrogram = mel_spectrogram_transform(waveform)
```

There are some more pre-processing steps in order to be able to save the spectrogram as an image, but I skip it here for brevity.
What makes me headaches is the inverse step. `torchaudio` has a function for that, `InverseMelScale`. But it is painstakingly slow. Here is the code:

```
inverse_melscale_transform = torchaudio.transforms.InverseMelScale(sample_rate=44100, n_mels=512, n_stft=2048 // 2 + 1).to(device)  
mel_spectrogram = mel_spectrogram.to(device)
spectrogram = inverse_melscale_transform(mel_spectrogram)
```

Again, I leave out the some more steps here, e.g., using `GriffinLim` to get the actual audio from `spectrogram`.

Here is what I did so far:
I ran the code on my MacBook Pro (Intel), which took forever. I then tested it on a AMD Ryzen server with 256 cores, where I was able to get the result within a couple of minutes. Now my idea was to utilize a GPU, a Titan XP in this case, to get the result even faster, but even after 30 minutes of computing with 100% GPU utilization, there is no result in sight.

What am I doing wrong?
Why is the AMD Ryzen so much faster?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, InverseMelScale is implemented as inference using SGD, that is inside of InverseMelScale, loss function is defined and optimizer run.

This implementation is not only inefficient, but also no accurate.

For the reason this implementation was picked, you can check out https://github.com/pytorch/audio/pull/366.

It is suggested to use L-BFGS-B optimizer
https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/2643

Comment: Wow, you must know a lot about pytorch!

Comment: I am the maintainer of torchaudio ;)